# python 3 http socket not working

Tags: python, sockets

My code:

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 8090
backlog = 5
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(backlog)
while 1:
    client, address = s.accept()
    #data = client.recv(size)


    data= "ok"

    if data:
        client.send(bytes('HTTP/1.0 200 OK<CRLF>', 'UTF-8'))
        client.send(bytes("Content-Type: text/html<CRLF><CRLF>", 'UTF-8'))
        client.send(bytes('<html><body><h1>Hello World</body></html>', 'UTF-8'))
    client.close()
```

for some reason whenever i visit:
http:localhost:8090 google chrome returns:

"The webpage at http:localhost:8090 might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

I looked up tons of examples, and I have no clue why this is not working

I am running python 3.3 on windows 7, thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<CRLF>` characters should be `\r\n` in python. If you then put the `.recv` back in it works:

```
import socket

host = ''
port = 8090
backlog = 5
size = 1024
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(backlog)
while 1:
    client, address = s.accept()
    data = client.recv(size)

    if data:
        client.send(bytes('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n', 'UTF-8'))
        client.send(bytes("Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n", 'UTF-8'))
        client.send(bytes('<html><body><h1>Hello World</body></html>', 'UTF-8'))
    client.close()
```

Python uses the backslash `\` character for escaping in strings. See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings for more details.